# iOS 7 - Presenting modal view controller selects first tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin, ios7

I'm working on a UITabBarController-based application for iOS with Xamarin, and while making some relatively small changes for iOS 7.0 compatibility, I found a particularly annoying issue that I am unable to solve.

A number of the view controllers that make up the UITabBarController have areas that require another view controller to be presented modally, sliding up from the bottom of the screen. In iOS 6.1, everything works fine.

However, in iOS 7 I've noticed that when the presented view controller is dismissed, the UITabBarController underneath has been navigated back to the first (leftmost) tab. This is very problematic, since any progress or information entered is lost.

Has anybody experienced this issue or, hopefully, found a solution?

Comment: I tried this in iOS 7, and I don't see what you're seeing -- it goes back tot he tab that presented it.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, I found out the cause of the problem. In order to fix this issue: [UITabBar appearance setSelectionIndicatorImage does not work on first launch iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820988/uitabbar-appearance-setselectionindicatorimage-does-not-work-on-first-launch-ios)

I had this code running in my UITabBarController's *ViewWillAppear* overridden method:

```
if ( Session.IsiOS7 )
{
    this.SelectedIndex = 1;
    this.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

This is being used to force the tab bar to display the selection indicator image, which it does not do by default in iOS 7. It also happens to cause this problem! I can't believe I didn't think of this right away.